# Why indexes are different from regular variables

Tags: c++, arrays

Can anyone explain me, please. Why in C++
    `array[i] = array[++i];`    doesn't work like    `array[i] = array[i + 1];`
but     `i = ++i;`    does work like    `i = i + 1;`

Comment: Q: Why are "indexes" different from "regular variables"?  A: they *aren't*!  Q: why doesn't `array[i] = array[++i];` work like `array[i] = array[i + 1];`?  A: You're relying on all the "Partial bexpressions" in your complex expression to always execute in the same order.  Sometimes they will, sometimes they won't.  This is an example of "undefined behavior".

Comment: Clarify "regular variable".  The variable `i` is usually a regular variable.

Comment: why doesn't it work then? =|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value evaluations of the left and right operands of the assignment operator are not sequenced.
Thus this expression

```
array[i] = array[++i];
```

can behave either like

```
array[i] = array[i + 1];
```

or like

```
array[i + 1] = array[i + 1];
```

On the other hand (C++ Standard)

> ...in all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation
>   of the right and left operands,

Thus in this expression

```
i = ++i;
```

the left operand will be overwritten by the value of ++i.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is regarding the return values of `pre-increment`, no increment and `post-increment`.

The expression `++i` increments the variable,then returns the incremented value.

The expression `i++` increments the variable, the *returns the value before incrementing*.

So, the expressions `array[i + 1]` and `array[++i]` refer the same element, **except array[++i] has the side effect of incrementing the index variable**.

Comment: "except array[++i] has the side effect of incrementing the index variable."
Thanks, that's what I was asking.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having is that you have misunderstood what is happening with `++i`.

`++i` is a statement saying increment *before* the evaluation of the current line and place that result in the expression. The reason `++i` works like just adding one and assigning is because that is essentially what it does! These statements are equivalent:

```
array[i] = array[ ++i ]
array[i] = array[ i = i + 1 ]
```

Remember that the assignment operator returns the value from the right hand side (the new value assigned). The *only* reason why that's different than just saying `array[i + 1]` is because of the side effect that `i` has been changed.

Now, about `i = ++i`. Using the same logic we can replace that with

```
i = (i = i + 1)
```

Observe now that once you have assigned `i`, you return the value on the right hand side...meaning of course that that is equivalent to:

```
i = i + 1
```